# Link two document with native driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two different collections in my database, and at this point I need to link a document from first collection to a document form second collection with native NodeJs driver.

How can I do that? Should I hold the `_id` from first collection in second collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would suggest storing the `_id` of the related document, manually, as you described. I've done that a lot, and it works well.

A more complex (and seemingly unnecessary in the case you describe), would be to use a [DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/).

Comment: Thanks mate. just another small question, `_id` is unique over the collection or whole database?

Comment: An _id only needs to be unique within a colleciton. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/